# how to search for 2 substrings in a list of tuples

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am having a database jobs list of tuple elements which looks like -

```
[('oraclehost.backup.b.c','oraclehost.backup.b.b'),('oraclehost.fullbackup.b.c','oraclehost.fullbackup.b.b'),
('oraclehost.incrbackup.b.c','oraclehost.incrbackup.b.b')]
```

The requirement here is to check if the 1st string and 2nd string in each element are matching i.e all the `'b.c'` are with the matching `'b.b'` .

I already have a function which takes a set of substrings and compares it with the jobs to see if they are present.
Now i am trying to put the above listed requirement through this function,but not sure how to define the substrings and if any modifications for the function are required.Please suggest.Thanks.

```
stdsubstrings = {'archivebackup.b', 'logbackup.b', 'fullbackup.b', 'dailybackup.b'}
presentjobs=['ora123.archivebackup.b','ora123.logbackup.b','ora123.fullbackup.b','ora123.dailybackup.b']

def check_jobs(stdsubstrings,presentjobs):
    FIND_FILE = re.compile('|'.join(s for s in stdsubstrings))
    matches = set()
    for boxjob in presentjobs:
        match = FIND_FILE.search(boxjob[0])
        if match:
            print(match.group(0), "found")
            matches.add(match.group(0))
```

Comment: why did you put `boxjob[0]` ?

Comment: The presentjobs were of the format ('ora123.archivebackup.b', ) when extracted.So had to use boxjob[0].But it can be changed as per the requirement to form a new function altogether.

Comment: post the expected output

Comment: it would be something like...if (all the 'b.c' and 'b.b' in the same element are matched): print ('all jobs are fine')    else: print('so and so b.c is not in the expected b.b)

Comment: You question Is easy to solve but you didn't really explain what you needed, The first you said list of tuple contains two elements, in the sample code is list of `str`? what do you need exactly to check if the first element have a special substring?